# reactjs, no infinite loop, how come?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, use-effect

I don't get it, I thought with below code, when I visit Fruit.js page/component('/fruits/:slug' route), it should cause an infinite loop... but it didn't, why? (I am glad it didn't, but just curious why?)

App.js

```
const App = () => {
    const [dummyData, setDummyData] = useState([
        { slug: 'apple', name: 'Apple', color: 'Red' },
        { slug: 'watermelon', name: 'Watermelon', color: 'Green' },
        { slug: 'peach', name: 'Peach', color: 'Pink' },
        { slug: 'banana', name: 'Banana', color: 'Yellow' },
    ]);

    const [fruitSlug, setFruitSlug] = useState('');

    const getSlug = (slug) => {
        setFruitSlug(slug);
        console.log(slug);
    };

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            {dummyData.map((fruit) => (
                <span className='fruit-link' key={fruit.slug}>
                    <Link to={`/fruits/${fruit.slug}`}>{fruit.name}</Link>{' '}
                </span>
            ))}

            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
                <Route
                    path='/fruits/:slug'
                    render={(props) => <Fruit {...props} getSlug={getSlug} />}
                />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Fruit.js

```
const Fruit = ({ getSlug }) => {
    const { slug } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        getSlug(slug);
    }, [getSlug, slug]);

    return (
        <div className='fruit'>
            <h1>Fruit page</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Fruit;
```

Comment: It would be useful to know why you think there should be an infinite loop

Comment: *"it should cause an infinite loop"* What makes you think that?

Comment: I am not sure if I am correct or not but the reason I think it will cause infinite loop is because: 
after visiting Fruit.js page/component, it does an initial render which execute ```getSlug(slug)``` and ```getSlug(slug)``` function runs => set new slug value to ```fruitSlug``` state => App.js re-render => ```getSlug(slug)``` function gets recreated and pass to Fruit.js page/component => ```useEffect``` in Fruit.js detects ```getSlug``` function is different which triggers useEffect and execute ```getSlug(slug)``` again, and repeat?? sorry reactjs beginner here.

Comment: I know that if I fetch an api calls and set the api response data to a state(example: ```setData(post)```) inside of ```getSlug``` function in App.js , I'll get infinite loop, but how come I am not getting an infinite loop with my above code...?? so if this is in ```getSlug``` function, it will cause infinite loop: ```fetch(postUrl).then((response) => response.json()).then((post) =>setData(post))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start of by giving two similar examples, removing some of the problem overhead present in your current question.

You are wondering why the `useEffect` callback in the snippet below does not trigger infinite re-renders.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function Example() {
  const [a, setA] = React.useState("");
  const [b, setB] = React.useState(a);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setB(a);
  }); // <- without dependencies triggers every render
    
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={a} onChange={e => setA(e.target.value)} />
      <p>{b}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

While it does seem to do so when you pass a more complex object from for example an API.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function Example() {
  const [a, setA] = React.useState("");
  const [b, setB] = React.useState({ value: a });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setB({ value: a });
  }); // <- without dependencies triggers every render
    
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={a} onChange={e => setA(e.target.value)} />
      <p>{b.value}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This is due to the simple fact that `useState` has a ["bail out" mechanism](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update):

> #### Bailing out of a state update
>
> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> (React uses the [`Object.is` comparison algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).)
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive
> calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with `useMemo`.

The first example would infinity trigger a re-render if it where not for this bail out mechanism. When React tries to set a state that is the same as the current state, it stops.

From APIs we often receive JSON, that gives us an complex object when parsed. Two objects are never equal to each other, even if they contain the same contents.

```
const a = { name: "John Doe" };
const b = { name: "John Doe" };
const c = a;

Object.is(a, b) //=> false
Object.is(a, c) //=> true
```

In the above example, although `a` and `b` contain the same contents, they are not the same object and are thus not equal to each other. Whereas `a` and `c` are both the same object, they are just two different labels referring to the same object. If you where to mutate `a`, `c` would also change. Therefore they are considered equal.

Parsing JSON always builds new objects and the result is therefore never equal (unless the JSON describes a primitive data type).

```
const json = '{ "name": "John Doe" }';
const a = JSON.parse(json);
const b = JSON.parse(json);

Object.is(a, b) //=> false
```

Comment: So basically with my codes, the reason that it didn't give me any kind of infinite loop behind the scene is because of reactjs's "bail out" mechanism,  so when I visit Fruit.js page/component, ```useEffect``` triggers and ```getSlug(slug)``` function executes and set the new value to ```fruitSlug``` state, which cause App.js to re-render, then it triggers ```useEffect``` in Fruit.js again and executes ```getSlug(slug)``` function again BUT when executing ```getSlug``` function, reactjs found out that the new value I am going to set to ```fruitSlug``` state is the

Comment: same value as the current one, so it didn't set the new value to ```fruitSlug``` state, which App.js re-render won't happen, so everything just stopped...am I correct?

Comment: @JustANewCoder Yes, you understood correctly.